# Django Querying ManytoMany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am creating a simple django project which deals with storage of name of Books and authors and storing list of to be read (TBR). The TBR table is connected to books table as many to many.

Now, I am confused in how to query the list of books that are in a specific TBR.

The code that I wrote is the following:

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def is_read(self):
        return self.filter(read='y')

    def is_not_read(self):
        return self.filter(read='n')

class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter a book genre (e.g. Science Fiction)')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Enter first name of the author",default="Unknown")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Enter last name of the author",default="Unknown")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

class Book(models.Model):

    YES = 'y'
    NO = 'n'

    DID_READ_CHOICES = [
        (YES,'Yes'),
        (NO,'No'),
    ]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        Author,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True,
        related_name='author_books'
        )
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text='Select a genre for this book')
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a brief description of the book',blank=True,null=True)
    read = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=DID_READ_CHOICES,
        default=NO,
        )

    objects = BookManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class TBR(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book = models.ManyToManyField(
        Book,
        related_name='in_tbr',
        )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am new to Django and I am referring the Django documentation, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

**Edit**: I tried the following:

```
>>> to_be_read = TBR.objects.get(title='TBR1')
>>> for book in to_be_read.book:
...     book.title
...
```

But got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   TypeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Comment: Let me understand better your question. You need to query the list of books based on your 'title' from the TBR model?

Comment: Yes, For example there is TBR called 'Books To read in a life time', Now out of 10 books only 7 are a part of the This TBR. Now I want to query only these 7 books based on the TBR.

Comment: Just a suggestion: It's not better to create a new category field in Book model to TBR (so you can create many categories as you want - like 'Books To read in a life time' and associate with the book and ado the query based in this field) and a BooleanField to check if it's TBR or not? Tell me if it's make any sense for your because life will be easier with this. If not I will made another solution.

Comment: Actually, I am making it for my mother who is an avid book reader. She finds this TBR's on pinterest and tries to get all the pdfs. As there is no way to manage it becomes a cluster. Therefore I decided to make this for her, and she can add her TBR's and add the books from all the book lists available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `book.all()`

try this

```
>>> to_be_read = TBR.objects.get(title='TBR1')
>>> for book in to_be_read.book.all():
...     book.title
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It works. I was stuck on this for a while